# Monitor a Java Native Interface applications

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights, azure-api-apps

Question: How to monitor a Java Native Interface applications; do we use a Java Agent or the VM Agent?

Based on my research I believe its via the Java agent but need a SME to confirm this is the recommended approach or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant here.

Comment: Is your query about monitoring java applications on *Azure*?